# Python IF condition with multiple variables

Tags: python, if-statement

Could someone clarify this. What happens if I try to write this code:

```
if tomato = 1 or tomato = 2 or tomato = 3
```

... like this:

```
if tomato = 1 or 2 or 3
```

I know Python doesn't consider it the same but what does it think I'm doing?

Most importantly, what's the best way to do this if I have a whole bunch of conditions for tomato. Writing "tomato =" each time doesn't seem very neat.

Answer (score 3):

Python doesn't think anything. It recognizes that there's something wrong with the syntax and throws a `SyntaxError`.

To simply check many values at once you can use the `in` operator:

```
if tomato in (1, 12, 25, 76, 84):
    pass
```

Also note that you have to use two equal signs (`==`) to check for equality.

Answer (score 0):

If you had been using double equal signs the execution would go as follows: Python starts evaluating the predicate of your `if` statement from left to right. If the value of `tomato` is 1 then the first part evaluates as `True` and the Python interpreter continues evaluating the consecutive lines inside the `if` block (this is called [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)).

However, if the value of `tomato` isn't 1, the interpreter continues by evaluating the next part in the predicate, which is an integer of value 2. All integer values, except for zero, evaluate as `True`. This results in the next part of the predicate evaluating as `True` and the interpreter continues to execute the contents of the `if` block. So your predicate is a [tautology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)) and always evaluates as `True` no matter what value `tomato` has.

As pointed out by pp_, you should use double equal signs for equality comparison - otherwise the statement is considered as an assignment and in Python, an assignment statement doesn't have a truth value so the interpreter throws you a `SyntaxError`.